# Android Automative Emulator

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

I have a problem with Android Automative emulators, the all different versions that I installed in my computer is run in portrate mode (vertically) and I test those in different version of android studio, emulators still run in portrate mode in all android studio that I installed and I can't rotate those in the landscape mode.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jD9W.png)

When I create a  new emulator I select the landcape mode so, Android Automative emulator must run in Landscape mode, but all of my Automative emulators is run in portrate mode and I can't rotate those tho the correct direction.